# Asp.net MVC authentication ticked without create auth cookie

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I'm authenticating a user in my application with the method "FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie" method, but when I close the browser and reopen it, it is still authenticated, but the session is over already, then my app crashes because it has necessary data on the session to generate the menus.

What I want to do is the following: Create an authentication ticket without create a auth cookie to, whenever the user open the page in a new browser session it will request the login once again.

How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

Sessions and authentication are different. If you want the cookie to go away when the browser closes then use

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("username", false);
```

Comment: Yep, basically don't give the user the option to create a persistent cookie - if you're using the default Account Controller from the ASP.NET MVC site, then change FormsAuth.SignIn(userName, rememberMe); to FormsAuth.SignIn(userName, false);

Answer (score 2):

Are there other browser windows open? Sometime if there are other browser windows open the cookie will persist.

Answer (score 0):

There is no properties on the either cookies or session to expire them when the browser is closed. They are only controlled by expiration time (Something that should have been thought of by whoever specified standards for cookies).

Passing false to SetAuthMethod will not tell browser to delete cookie when the browser is closed. In fact, if browser has an option enabled to return to the tabs that were left open, it will reopen these tabs with all cookies that were there. If these authentication cookies did not expire yet, you will find your self logged in.

What you can do, is specify different expiration time for when user checks "Remember Me" vs when he does not check it:

```
// create this private method.
private void SetAuthCookie(string emailAddress, bool keepMeLoggedIn)
{
    int timeout = keepMeLoggedIn ? 525600 : 20; // Timeout in minutes, 525600 = 365 days.
    var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(emailAddress, keepMeLoggedIn, timeout);
    string encrypted = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
    var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encrypted);
    cookie.Expires = System.DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(timeout);
    cookie.HttpOnly = true; // cookie not available in JavaScript.
    HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}

// use it instead of FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.username, model.RememberMe);
SetAuthCookie(model.username, model.RememberMe);
```